# TFS delete folder and recursive deletes

Tags: tfs, tf-cli

If I delete a folder in TFS (using the GUI or TF.exe) - everything under that folder is marked as deleted. Is there any point in doing a recursive delete on a folder??
I see the benefits of using the

> -recursive

switch if there is a need to pattern match something but for a full folder delete does it make any difference?

Comment: Practically there is no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference for full folder delete. As you can see [in documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k45zb450.aspx) the -recursive parameter makes sence only when used with some pattern. If you don't use any the result will be the same - all files and folders marked as 'Deleted'.